# How to select elements from right to left?

Tags: c#, string, character

For example if I have the user inputting a string but with unknown length and I want to take the 3rd element from right to left, how can I do this? In Python its like string[-2] but that's not working in C#..

For example:

```
string whatever = "snfdsjzfs";
```

I want to select the z and using `string[6]` is not going to help me since the string length might change..?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. The common sense is to [not include tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them)

Answer (score 1):

Combine using [`String.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string.chars) indexer and [`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) property:

```
int num = ...; // num-th (zero based) char to extract from the end to start
if (num > whatever.Length-1){
    // error handling here
}    
char res = whatever[whatever.Length-num-1];
```

Comment: it's `whatever[whatever.Length-num-1]`.  You have an off by one error.  Zero-indexed collections, one-indexed length, and all that.

Comment: @Servy Note that it is for `num-th char from the end`, like the 1st will be `whatever[hatever.Length-1]`.

Comment: The OP's example used a zero-indexed index from the right hand side, which is of course what most any programmer would expect, because they're programmers, and indexes are therefore zero indexed.